# SwiftUI Foreach OutOfMemory / OutOfRange

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have some problem with making a loop in Swift/SwiftUI.

--Result bad performance and not release memory = OutOfMemory

```
ForEach(model.model) { item in
   Text(item.name)
}
```

--Result OutOfRange because of model is updated in background

```
ForEach(model.model.indices) { i in
   Text(model.model[i].name)
}
```

--Result bad performance and not release memory = OutOfMemory

```
ForEach($model.model) { $item in
   Text($item.wrappedValue.name)
}
```

Comment: How many items are in your `model`?  Perhaps a `LazyVGrid` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Third time this week I removed a swift3 tag from a question, are people mistakenly using this very old swift version for SwiftUI 3?

Comment: @Paulw11
I have a 95 sections with a about 7 rows..
The above example is very simplified.
`
ForEach Section
-Header
-ForEach Row
--View2

View2
LazyVGrid (Fixed and 1 adaptive)
 Some LazyVStack with image/text
`
I can't scroll down once without memory allocation failure (600Mb) without indices on the loop.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson
Sorry, added everything that I thought was related, don't know version on it.

Comment: What do your model and data model look like?

Comment: Yes I suppose there is a mistake in your model structs (perhaps not implemented Identifiable correctly) or maybe your environment object holding the model structs array has a mistake.

Comment: Also, post a true example of the structure. It doesn't help to put up a basic example, that doesn't reflect what you are actually doing.